# NetSuite API Insert Phone Call

Tags: netsuite

I've successfully created a phone call record in netsuite and related it to a company record. However, I haven't been able to relate a phone call to a contact record. Where am I going wrong?

**Error**

```
{
   "message": "Invalid contact reference key 43780 for company <NULL>.",
   "code": "INVALID_KEY_OR_REF"
}
```

Note: Internal ID 4370 is a contact in netsuite

**Envelope with variables**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soap:Header>
        <applicationInfo xmlns="urn:messages_2015_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
            <applicationId>_appId_</applicationId>
        </applicationInfo>
            <preferences xmlns="urn:messages_2015_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
        <warningAsError>false</warningAsError>
        </preferences>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <update xmlns="urn:messages_2015_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
            <record internalId="_callId_" xmlns:q1="urn:scheduling_2015_2.activities.webservices.netsuite.com" xsi:type="q1:PhoneCall">
                <q1:message>_description_</q1:message>
                <q1:title>_name_</q1:title>
                <q1:assigned internalId="_user_" type="contact"/>
                <q1:contact internalId="_customer_" type="contact"/>
                <q1:phone>_number_</q1:phone>
                <q1:startDate>_startDate_</q1:startDate>
                <q1:endDate>_endDate_</q1:endDate>
                <q1:timedEvent>true</q1:timedEvent>
            </record>
        </update>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: That error means that you are not sending the company along with the contact, or you are specifically sending a null value.  Try adding in the company that the contact is associated with.

Comment: Thanks for the response. In this case, there is no company associated to the contact. Does a phone call expect a company to be related?